# Android: Error de firma al publicar apk

Tags: android, apk

Estoy siguiendo los pasos indicados en la siguiente ruta: 
    https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html
para firmar mi APK, pero al subirlo al PlayStore me envía un mensaje que indica: *Subiste un archivo APK sin firma. Debes crear un archivo APK firmado*.

Ya lo he generado varias veces y no se que más hacer para generar mi APK firmada.

Comment: Estas seguro que haces los pasos como corresponde? Puedes adjuntar imagenes de paso a paso como estas generando la key y firmandola?

Comment: Tienes que crear un Keystore para firmar tu aplicación en Google Playstore. Agregué respuesta.

Comment: tienes puesto el sabor a release? y despues generar apk signado

Answer (score 1):

Puedes encontrar la información en la documentación:

**[FIRMAR TU APP !](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html?hl=es-419)**

Primeramente necesitas obtener un Keystore de producción para firmar la aplicación, eso se realiza mediante la utilería `keytool` esto es un ejemplo:

```
keytool -list -keystore your_keystore_name

keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name
```

Pero ahora para mayor facilidad puedes usar este método:

[**Firmar tu compilación de versión**](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html?hl=es-419#release-mode) (Si deseas crear un keystore nuevo, haz clic en Create new.)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el archivo .keystore que obtengas debes firmar tu aplicación, desde el menú de Android Studio puedes realizarlo, te requerira la ruta de tu keystore:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo el mismo proceso pero en linea de comandos para Linux:

Generar llave:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_keystone -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Firmar apk existente:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore llave_generada_antes.keystore android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk alias_keystore
```

Cambiar el nombre de la apk:

```
zipalign -v 4 android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk NombreApp.apk
```