# ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_SIGNATURES - Google Playstore

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, compilar, google-play-console

Estoy intentando subir una aplicacion a la playstore, el problema, es que siempre tira el mismo error.
Voy a explicar los pasos que realize...

> 1)Build -> generate singed bundle / apk
>
> 2)Selecciono APK
>
> 3)Creo una Key store path por que la de debug no sirve para release
>
> 4)Build variants 'release' y signature Versions V1 y V2 (min android
>   5.0, max 9.0)
>
> 5)Finish

Cuando intento subir la APK a la playstore siempre me da este error, probe con las 3 combinaciones posibles de signature, pero nada!

[image: error]

Estoy intentado subir una version ALFA, no se si me estoy olvidando un paso o que, busque por todos lados y todos explican lo mismo, no le encuentro la forma.

Comment: Tal vez te sirva ver este post: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60897/android-error-de-firma-al-publicar-apk

Comment: @FernandoCarraro Lo revise, pero de momento eso lo hice, lo explique en los puntos anteriores :c

Comment: @LcsGrz puedes revisar los datos que tiene tu keystore .jks, me refiero a la fecha de caducidad de la misma, ¿tu aplicación es nativa o usas react?

Comment: @Elenasys probre creando dos keystores distintas una tiene una caducidad de 25 años y la otra de 100, la aplicacion es nativa y es la primera ves que intento subirla a la PlayStore, quiero subir una version ALFA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la solucion!

No se realmente cual fue el problema, pero si creo la KEYSTORE desde android studio NO FUNCIONA!

Los pasos que realize los extraje de sus respuestas y comentarios

> 1)Arir CMD
>
> 2)Ir a C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin
>
> 3) keytool -genkey -v -keystore {NOMBRE}.keystore -alias {ALIAS}
>   -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
>
> 4)Completar con el resto de los datos necesarios
>
> 5)Desde Android Studio especifique la nueva KEYSTORE
>
> 6)Funciono la subida a la PlayStore

Gracias por ayudar!

Comment: Sinceramente no sabía que se creaba el keystore desde Android Studio, la documentación dice que debe ser creada mediante la utilería "keytool", ¿Como creas el keystore desde Android Studio?

Comment: @Elenasys revisa este post https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60897/android-error-de-firma-al-publicar-apk , de todas formas, en la documentacion menciona lo mismo, de este link https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing?hl=es-419#release-mode lee 'Generar una clave y un keystore'

Answer (score 2):

Cuando firmes tu .APK debes firmarlo en modo de publicación y no en modo de depuración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El .APK que se encuentra dentro del directorio`/relesase` de tu proyecto es el que debes usar ya que el que se encuentra dentro del directorio `/debug` no es el adecuado para subir a Google Play no importando si es para una publicación Alpha o Beta.

---

En cuanto a  este punto:

> 3)Creo una Key store path por que la de debug no sirve para release

No debes crear otro Keystore, debes usar el mismo con el cual firmaste inicialmente tu aplicación en Google Play.

Revisar :

[Obtén más información sobre las firmas.](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

Comment: Hola!, lo que me comentaste es como lo estoy haciendo, lo mencione en los pasos que realize, de todas formas sigue pasando lo mismo, tengo error en los SIGNATURE

Comment: @LcsGrz el apk que deseas subir es una actualización? Si es así recuerda que debes usar  el mismo keystore.

Comment: No, es la primera apk que intento subir, realice los pasos que mencione arriba pero no hay forma, lo unico que note es que la nueva keystore que se crea con android studio termina en '.jks' mientras que que la de debug en '.keystore'

Comment: @LcsGrz ok debes usar  '.jks' para que se firme adecuadamente para playstore y toma el .apk que se genera el /release

Comment: estoy utilizando esa, que es la que creo con android studio.No entiendo por que siempre sale el mismo error, busque en todos lados y todos encuentran solucion menos yo :C